# Dynamic PCollection per input

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have this pipeline which get set of URL's based on the dynamic input for the job.
My problem is to access the dynamic value of `source` which `source.get()` does not return anything but the default value and in general I want to behind the `fetch_urls` to some PCollection function.

Looking at [Python transform catalog overview](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/overview/) I could not find something to answer my request.

How I can set a PCollection based on dynamic value that fetch some values.

Thanks

```
def fetch_urls(source):
    sources = source.get()
    # some logic
    return urls
              
class UserOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):

        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--source',
            default='my_source',
            type=str,
            help='my_source')   
                
def run():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    args, beam_args = parser.parse_known_args()
    
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
    custom_options = pipeline_options.view_as(UserOptions)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        
        urls = fetch_urls(custom_options.source)

        results = (p | 'Set URLs' >> beam.Create(urls)
                        | 'Strip' >> beam.Map(str.strip))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are only getting the default value is because you are attempting to use a runtime value provider during pipeline construction time. Runtime value providers are meant to allow values to be specified for your pipeline after it has been constructed, just before it begins executing. However the `fetch_urls` function you wrote is executing while you are constructing the pipeline, not when your pipeline executes.

Above you posted a "workaround":

```
results = (p | 'Set path' >> beam.Create([custom_options.urls])
             | 'Map URls' >> beam.FlatMap(fetch_urls)
             | 'Strip' >> beam.Map(str.strip))
```

This is not actually hacky or a workaround, it is a fine solution. What's happening is that you create a PCollection containing the value provider itself instead of the raw value. When pipeline execution begins, the value provider has been populated, gets placed into a PCollection, then passed to `fetch_urls`, and finally has `get()` called on it and outputs the populated value.

The key difference is that `get()` is being called in execution time because `fetch_urls` is being executed as a transform, instead of called directly during construction time.

For further reading, I recommend reading the [Creating Templates documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#python_2) on the Dataflow website. It has further explanations and examples of how to use value providers in your pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

I found some hack for work around

```
results = (p | 'Set path' >> beam.Create([custom_options.urls])
             | 'Map URls' >> beam.FlatMap(fetch_urls)
             | 'Strip' >> beam.Map(str.strip))
```